# Select multiple rows with condition on each columns

Tags: postgresql, select

I am sure this could be very silly question, but I was not able to find answer from the internet.

I am trying to select rows with this conditon.

Select all rows if Side has both 'Right' and 'Left'.

[image]

In this case, it will select both row of Id 3 and 4 (yellow highlighted ones).

I know bottom query is not going to work.

select * from "Table" where ("Side" = 'Right') or ("Side" = 'Left')

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You need a join. If your table name is processes

```
select 
 p.*
from processes p

inner join processes p2
on p.pid = p2.pid 
and p.id <> p2.id
and p.side <> p2.side
```

Answer (score 0):

You may filter it using a `WHERE` &  `HAVING` clause in a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT *
  FROM t
    WHERE pid IN (
       SELECT pid
           FROM t
          WHERE side IN (
           'Right',
           'Left' )
     GROUP BY pid
     HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT side) = 2 )
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f2b01abee9cb4906fccd39ab95a76a05)